# VS Code / how do you define custom "go to definition"?

Tags: laravel, alias, visual-studio-code

Ive got a small problem here with VS Code while using it to work on Laravel. See there are `aliases` defined in laravel and the VSCode simply doesnt know where there are. So go to definition doesnt work at all for them.

for example: the following works and any method called from this helper will click-open:

```
use App\Http\Helpers\pdfHelper;
```

However, this wont work:

```
use dPDF;
```

Which is defined in the `app.php` as:

```
'dPDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

Similar to this ive got like 50 other aliases. So is there a way to set a custom list of go-tos in VS Code?

Comment: I think the solution may be to add a plugin, like PHP Intelephense at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client. This provides F12 support for Laravel vendor classes for me without configuration.